# asp.net + Accessing HiddenField value assigned in JS on Postback from CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to access my hiddenfield values from code behind but I got empty values instead, what I am doing here is setting the 2 hiddenfield values from a Javascript function and after that do a postback via asp:button click. Not sure what am I doing wrong here, please kindly assist:

Thanks.

```
 <form id="Form1" class="form" runat="server">

            <p class="SearchAddress">
                <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextField" runat="server" />
                <label for="searchTextField">
                    Location</label>
            </p>
            <p class="Date">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server">18/10/2012</asp:TextBox>
                <label for="txtDate">
                    Date</label>
            </p>
            <p class="TimeFrom">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TimeFrom" runat="server">18:00</asp:TextBox>
                <label for="txtTimeFrom">
                    Time From</label>
            </p>
            <p class="TimeTo">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TimeTo" runat="server">19:00</asp:TextBox>
                <label for="txtTimeTo">
                    Time To</label>
            </p>

            <p class="submit">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCalculateCoordinates" runat="server" Text="Post It!" 
                  onClientclick="calculateCoordinates();" onclick="btnCalculateCoordinates_Click" 
            />
           </p>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnlLatLong" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                         <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLatitude" runat="server"  />
                         <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLongitude" runat="server" />
             </ContentTemplate>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </form>

      function calculateCoordinates() {
                    var txtAddress1 = document.getElementById('<%=searchTextField.ClientID%>');
                    var txtLat = document.getElementById('<%=txtLatitude.ClientID%>');
                    var txtLng = document.getElementById('<%=txtLongitude.ClientID%>');

                    var address = txtAddress1.value + ', ';

                    var geocoder;
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                            txtLat.value = location.lat(); //SETTING THE HIDDENFIELD VALUE
                            txtLng.value = location.lng(); //SETTING THE HIDDENFIELD  VALUE
                        }
                        else
                            alert('Opps, sorry but we are unable to locate' + $(txtAddress1).val());
                    });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the command generated the event in update panel as well to get the hidden . field values. You need to put all control in update panel those participate in ajax call.

```
<form id="Form1" class="form" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnlLatLong" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLatitude" runat="server"  />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLongitude" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCalculateCoordinates" runat="server" Text="Post It!"  onClientclick="calculateCoordinates();" onclick="btnCalculateCoordinates_Click" />
```

You can use ajax event begin_request of asp .net to call ajax method before call goes on server.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
       calculateCoordinates();
}
```

Comment: The ScriptManager and UpdatePanel should be inside the form.

Comment: This doesn't work, I guess the postback runs my server method first therefore couldn't grap my HiddenField value. What I did was call the button click from my Javascript after successfully setting the values.

Comment: Thats good to hear that you did it by other method. Javascript method has to be called first before the ajax call by principle you can check by debugging both javascript and code behind. You can put simple alert in javascript and break point on server to know the sequence they are being called

Comment: I have added a method to ensure javascript method call before ajax request, I hope it should help.